# Design Rows in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Hi I'm learning Flutter,
below is the design which I'm trying to achieve, 
Could I get the code snippet for first row, so that basing on that I'll try to create remaining 
 here is github https://github.com/phanivaranasi/blood_donar.git  
pages/dashboard.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:red_cross_hyd/components/header.dart';
import 'package:red_cross_hyd/pages/login.dart';

class DashboardPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  DashboardPageState createState() => DashboardPageState();
}

class DashboardPageState extends State<DashboardPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final content = Scaffold(
        appBar: header,
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: new Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
              height: 120,
              width: double.maxFinite,
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  
                ],
              )
            ),
          ],
        )));
    return content;
    //return new WillPopScope(child: content, onWillPop: () async => false);
  }
}
```

Icons CC: [Flat Icons]([https://www.flaticon.com/]](https://www.flaticon.com/%5D)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I request you to please update your question, with the issue you are facing. Flutter provides multiple widgets that can help with the layout shown above. The [GridView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html) Widget seems to be a perfect fit for the UI shown above.

Comment: Yes @Rohan Thacker, Grid view helped me to achieve design.  Now I'm developing contact us page